# How to properly send different parameters down for a standard Button Click

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I know this has to have an easy answer, but I'm utterly failing to fathom the wealth of information on custom events, event handlers, and delegates. I have a custom messagebox class. I am trying to add the capability to do something based off of the state of a check box if the OK button is clicked. The buttons and the checkbox are added dynamically based upon input into a static `Show` method somewhat like the following:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(suicideCheckboxID))
{
    suicideCheckBox = new CheckBox();
    suicideCheckBox.AutoSize = true;
    suicideCheckBox.Text = "Do not show this message again.";
    suicideCheckBox.Location = new Point(xMargin, label.Bottom + yMargin);
    suicideCheckBox.Checked = false;

    suicideCheckBoxHeight = suicideCheckBox.Height;

    form.Controls.Add(suicideCheckBox);
}

Button okButton = NewButton(DialogResult.OK, scaleFactor);

int x = (form.Width - okButton.Width) / 2;
okButton.Location = new Point(x, buttonYPosition);

form.Controls.Add(okButton);
form.AcceptButton = okButton;
form.CancelButton = okButton;
```

That's not the exact code, but it's fairly representative. My impulse is to use `okButton.Clicked += new EventHandler(OKButton_clicked)`, but if I do that, the event generated only carries arguments for `object sender` and `EventArgs e` and I really need it to operate off of the state of the checkbox and an additional piece of text to indicate which messagebox is being shown so that the values can be stored in the registry.

My first attempt was to do something like `okButton.Clicked += processSuicideCheckbox(suicideCheckboxID, suicideCheckBox);`, but that seems to just process the contents and allow one to return an `EventHandler` that points to a method with the signature of `object sender` and `EventArgs e`. What am I missing here? What is the best way to pass in the arguments actually relevant to me?

Comment: Do you need access to the status of `SuicideCheckbox` from within your custom `MessageBox` or from the calling form?

Comment: From within the custom MessageBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get to choose what is in the event handler for the `Click` event. Microsoft has already done that. You are stuck with the `(object sender, EventArgs e)` signature.

You do have a couple options:

1. Simply store the state in the class itself; the event handler will have access to it because it is inside the class.
2. Utilize a closure to do the same thing:

   ```
   myButton.Click += (s, e) => ActualFunction(checkBox1.Checked);
   ```

Note that using the closure (via a lambda expression) is just hiding the details of maintaining this state (creating the class-level variables).

Comment: I wound up using the second option above and it works fine. Thank you.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Glad I was able to help!